# Editing posts for grammar

Tags: discussion, editing

Over the last few weeks, I have discovered that, as most of you probably already know, a lot of questions and answers have very poor grammar. My question is, is editing these to increase the clarity of the post advised or unadvised?

The first answer here is a good example of what I mean. [Galaxy Note 2 stuck at Samsung logo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124748/galaxy-note-2-stuck-at-samsung-logo)

Comment: Well yes, you should. Checkout help center: http://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, please edit them! Better grammar makes a post more readable - everybody benefits.

A few caveats though. Don't go "fixing" American English into British English or vice versa.
And while editing, try to fix as much as you reasonably can - the right capitalization, markdown, and removal of noise.

On Meta Stack Overflow, I created a [proposal for a FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/812149) with help for editors. While that post is aimed specifically at Stack Overflow, I believe that most of it will be helpful on other sites as well.